# Is there a performance penalty for scala functions with implicit parameters?

Tags: scala, performance, class, methods, implicit

The code below shows consistent results on my machine: the code without implicits performs better

```
case class Config(appName: String, timeout: Int)

def appendWithImplicit(str: StringBuilder)(implicit config: Config): String = {
  val temp = new StringBuilder()
  temp.append(str).append(config.appName)
  temp.toString()
}

def appendNoImplicit(str: StringBuilder, appName: String, timeout:Int): String = {
  val temp = new StringBuilder()
  temp.append(str).append(appName)
  temp.toString()
}

implicit val config = Config("myapp", 100)
val iterations = 100000


var start = System.currentTimeMillis()
for(i <- 1 to iterations)
  appendWithImplicit(new StringBuilder(100, "foo"))
var end = System.currentTimeMillis()
println("method with implicit " + (end-start))


start = System.currentTimeMillis()
for(i <- 1 to iterations)
  appendNoImplicit(new StringBuilder(100, "foo"), config.appName, config.timeout)
end = System.currentTimeMillis()
println("method no implicit " + (end-start))
```

Is it something specific to my methods ?
is is something related to the implicits in scala ?

Comment: You are not doing performance testing correctly, so any results you derive are meaningless. - Anyways, no, in theory, there should be no runtime penalty since `implicit` is a compile-time only concept. After compilation `implicit` becomes just another parameter of the method.

Comment: I know that this is not proper performance testing, but I was amazed by the consistent results.

Comment: @humbletrader what's even more amazing if you reverse the order of your measurements ("method no implicit" before "method with implicit"), you will get a similar effect but with "method with implicit" seemingly faster. So what is indeed consistent is: the second batch of 100000 iterations in your code will always be faster (you will also get the same results if you call the same method in both for-comprehensions).

Comment: Adding up to what's already said: 1) in runtime implicits are just argument passed for you, 2) a method with multiple parameter lists in has just one parameter list with metadata in bytecode, 3) you are comparing `method(strBuilder, config)` to `method(strBuilder, str, int)` so they aren't even the same things 4) this is not a proper JVM benchmark, if it's not using JVM I would assume it's wrong (but using JMH on its own doesn't make it right).

Comment: There's also absolutely no guarantee that at some point in the benchmarks that the methods are even being called: even a fairly simple JIT will decide fairly quickly that there's no externally visible effect of the method (you're not doing anything to the passed-in `StringBuilder` and the value is being discarded) so there's no reason to even call the method.  That said, I'd expect a version which passes in `config.appName` to slightly outperform a version which just passes `config` until the whole thing is inlined (after which they'll be identical).

Comment: Thank you all for your input. All of your comments make sense. I would consider the finding of @MartinHH as an answer ( if he's kind enough to add his comment as an answer)